# How to keep items in cart even after refresh using vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex, cart, shopping-cart

The problems i am facing are -

- My state become empty when I refresh the page
- same occurs when i logout and then login

I am new to vuex and I want to build a functioning cart for my e-commerce site.

My cart store is as follows (ps. I have only made a very simple outline to check if it is working as desired):

```
let dayCare = window.localStorage.getItem('dayCare');

const state = { 
    dayCare: dayCare ? JSON.parse(dayCare) : [],
    
};

const getters = { 
    dayCareItems (state){
        return state.dayCare
    }

};

const actions = { 
    dayCareCart({commit}, dayCare){
        let data = dayCare
        commit('pushDaycareToCart', data)
        return data
        commit('saveCart')
    },
    
};

const mutations = {
    pushDaycareToCart(state, data){
        return state.dayCare.push(data)
        
    },
    saveCart(state) {
        window.localStorage.setItem('dayCare', JSON.stringify(state.dayCare));
        
    }
};


export default {
    state,
    actions,
    mutations,
    getters
};
```

the data for my cart comes from :

```
<button type="submit"  @click="dayCareCart(cartData)">Add To Cart</button>

<script>
import {mapGetters, mapActions} from 'vuex'
export default {
  methods: {
   ...mapActions(["dayCareCart"]),
  }
}
</script>
```

I want to know what i should add to retain the data for the logged in user

Comment: Save your cart in cookies?

Comment: Can you pls tell how to do that? @Hackinet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to persist the cart. The save mutation should be called in the push to cart mutation

```
let dayCare = window.localStorage.getItem('dayCare');

const state = {
    dayCare:  dayCare ? JSON.parse(dayCare) :[],
};
const getters = { 
    dayCareItems (state){
        return state.dayCare
    }
};
const actions = {
    dayCareCart({commit}, dayCare){
        commit('pushDaycareToCart', dayCare)
    },
};
const mutations = {
    pushDaycareToCart(state, dayCare){      
        state.dayCare.push(dayCare)
        this.commit('saveCart') 
    },
    saveCart(state) {
        window.localStorage.setItem('dayCare', JSON.stringify(state.dayCare));
    },
};
export default {
    state,
    actions,
    mutations,
    getters
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you expect it to persist data? You aren't using any kind of database to store the data.

Comment: I tried using local storage by taking reference from [link](http://www.voerro.com/en/tutorials/r/simple-persistent-shopping-cart-implementation-with-vuejs-2-and-vuex-in-laravel-5/2). It still doesnt work. I dont know where im going wrong

Comment: If i am correct, you are storing data in the database but not retrieving it back. Try console.loging the the data from localstorage and see if it gives you the data back

Answer (score 0):

Use the vuex plugin [vuex-persist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-persist). You can use it to persist data to localstorage or cookies while using everything awesome bout vuex